# Null data when posting getDates from Multidatespicker into jquery ajax post request

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-multidatespicker

HTML:

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
        var min = new Date(2017, 03, 01);
        var max = new Date(2017, 05, 30);
        $("#datepicker").multiDatesPicker({
            maxPicks: 21, numberOfMonths: [1, 3], dateFormat: 'd.m.y', defaultDate: '1.4.17', minDate: min, maxDate: max, onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                $("#save").text("Speichern").removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-default")
            }
        });
        $("#datepicker").addClass("center");
    });
</script>
<script>
    function speichern() {
        var url;
        var success;
        var data;
        var error;
        var dataType = "text";
        $("#save").text("Wird gespeichert...");
        success = function (ergebnis) {
            $("#save").text("Gespeichert").removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success");
        };
        url = "saver/save";
        data = {'dates[]': $("#datepicker").multiDatesPicker("getDates")};
        error = function (event, jqXHR, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError.toLocaleString());
        }
        $.post({url: url, success: success, data: data, error: error, dataType: dataType});
    }
</script><p>
<div id="datepicker"></div></p>
<button id="save" class="btn btn-default" style="float:right;margin-bottom: 10px" onclick="speichern()">Speichern</button>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

class saver extends CI_Controller
{
    function save()
    {
        $dates = $this->input->post['dates[]'];
        var_dump($dates);
        echo $dates;
        //echo "erfolgreich gespeichert";
    }
}
```

$dates is empty, but i really dont know why! Also tried 'data','dates','data'... for post['dates[]'], but nothing worked. data is an object (for some reason?) containing the array with the selected dates. Response from the PHP-Script is NULL. Send Parameters are e.g.: dates[]:"12.6.17"

EDIT: It has to be a CodeIgniter Bug because $_POST gives me what i want!

Answer (score 0):

In javascript array's are created as:

```
var dates = [] OR var dates = new Array();
```

So change your script code as below:

```
<script>
    function speichern() {
        var url;
        var success;
        var data;
        var error;
        dates = [];
        dates = $("#datepicker").multiDatesPicker("getDates");
        var dataType = "text";
        $("#save").text("Wird gespeichert...");
        success = function (ergebnis) {
            $("#save").text("Gespeichert").removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-success");
        };
        url = "saver/save";
        data = {'dates':dates};
        error = function (event, jqXHR, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError.toLocaleString());
        }
        $.post({url: url, success: success, data: data, error: error, dataType: dataType});
    }
</script>
```

And in php:

```
$date = $this->input->post('dates');
print_r($date);
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: I changed my script as you suggested, but the result is the same. The problem is not on the sending, but on the receiving side, because data is transmitted successfully.